# Seeking low level code to change the background color of ActionMenu menuitems

Tags: color, background

Currently, v13, the background color of the menuitems used in an ActionMenu are grey. Can the background be changed with some undocumented feature? This is for GUI reasons for visually impaired folks, like me. ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Will something like this: `ActionMenu[Style["Print Factorials", Bold, White], {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], "10!" :> Print[10!]}, Background -> Red]` help? Or something like this: `ActionMenu[
 Style["Print Factorials", Bold, 
  White], {Style["4!", 16, Bold] :> Print[4!], 
  Style["7!", 16, Bold] :> Print[7!], 
  Style["10!", 16, Bold] :> Print[10!]}, Background -> Red]`?

Comment: Thanks for trying. Nope, there remains the pale grey background surrounding the text of the menuitem. Perhaps on Windows you can do this; can you provide a screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and I did not find how to change the background of the fall-down menu. However, if it is the vision problems maybe it helps if you play with the style of the button text. It is like I proposed in the second code. You might try, for example, ` Style["7!", 20, Bold, Red] :> Print[7!]`, that is, the letter size 20 instead of 16 or automatically chosen 12. Then you may make color of your liking.